# Directing to custom error page on 404 triggered by a URL with '.' at the end

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

In my web.config I have the following:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="~/error" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
  <error redirect="~/error" statusCode="404" />
  <error redirect="~/error" statusCode="500" />
</customErrors>
...
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
  <clear />
  <remove statusCode="404" />
  <remove statusCode="403" />
  <remove statusCode="401" />
  <error statusCode="404" path="~/Error" responseMode="ExecuteURL" prefixLanguageFilePath="" />
  <remove statusCode="500" />
  <error statusCode="500" path="~/Error" responseMode="ExecuteURL" prefixLanguageFilePath="" />
</httpErrors>
```

In my `global.asax` I have the following:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do whatever you want to do with the error

        //Show the custom error page...
        //Server.ClearError();
        RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values["controller"] = "Error";

        Exception exception = Context.Server.GetLastError();
        if (exception != null && !ExceptionUtilities.IsExceptionIgnored(exception))
            ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(exception);

        Server.ClearError();

        HttpException httpException = Context.Server.GetLastError() as HttpException;
        if (httpException != null && ((Context.Server.GetLastError() is HttpException) && (httpException.GetHttpCode() != 404)))
        {
            routeData.Values["action"] = "Index";
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle 404 error and response code
            Response.StatusCode = 404;
            routeData.Values["action"] = "NotFound";
        }
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true; // If you are using IIS7, have this line
        IController errorsController = new ErrorController();
        HttpContextWrapper wrapper = new HttpContextWrapper(Context);
        RequestContext rc = new System.Web.Routing.RequestContext(wrapper, routeData);
        errorsController.Execute(rc);
    }


}
```

When I navigate to `http://localhost:56469/sss` I get the custom error page I created for this. However when I navigate to `http://localhost:56469/sss.` (note the period) I get the ugly yellow IIS screen stating `The resource cannot be found.`

What do I need to do to cover this "flavor" of `404`?

Comment: Have you tried adding `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />` to your web.config?

Comment: @DavidG - yes, same results.

Comment: Please do not add voting/closure commentary into questions themselves. It is better to do it in comments anyway, since the handle is more likely to ping the closer here than in your post.

Comment: For @Nkosi, from the OP: I appreciate your vigilance here but I'm asking to handle the error appropriately, not to ignore the `.`. Please revoke your flag asap as it is erroneous.

Comment: @SB2055. I recreated your problem with the [mcve] provided. In looking for a solution I came across the duplicated question Something you are suppose to do before asking already asked questions. Applying the answer handled the error which indicated to me that this question was in fact a duplicate of the stated post.